# My app was terminated after was installed from Xcode one day. And my Provisioning Profiles of development have issue follow picture

Tags: ios

[my Provisioning Profiles of development have issue follow picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmXFL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you generated the certificate a year ago. You should regenerate Development certificates every year.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#Resetting%20Certificates%20Using%20Xcode) you can find instruction to regenerate the certificate.

Comment: It's hard to tell from that screenshot, but you most likely recreated the certificate, thereby making the existing one invalid. In the latest xcode there is a button under `signing` in your app target section, which will make Xcode automatically manage your signing for you.

Comment: Because it was happened yesterday, i recreated the certificate again. So I can sure the certificate was not expired.But I really can not find what is issue.When my app was terminate I found my Provisioning Profiles state is Invailed.

Comment: Also you should regenerate with new certificate and reinstall your provision profiles. And rebuild the application with new provision profile

Comment: Thank your suggestion. But I use your method to regenerate and reinstall yesterday, but today the issue was happened again.I feel much sad and cry no tears.